# Get a list of all the blocks

Tags: blocks

I need an array of all blocks in the site

For example, if I display the array, it should output the block info or block titles e.g Search, User etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673773/in-drupal-7-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-blocks-being-used-on-the-page)

```
global $theme;
$all_regions = system_region_list($theme);
$blocks = array();
foreach (array_keys($all_regions) as $region) {
  $blocks += block_list($region);
}
```

Comment: Getting following error Fatal error: Call to undefined function system_region_list()

Comment: It is a valid drupal 7 function http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_region_list/7. Which version of Drupal you are using ???

Comment: It is a valid function for Drupal 6 as well. Check if the system module exist and it has the proper read permissions.

Comment: I am using drupal 7 and i have checked system module it exists and it has proper read permission. 
when i am calling it at hook_page_build function it works fine, but i am calling it in my custom function then i am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function system_region_list()

Comment: I need simply all the list of block names at custom url. I think it should not be any relation with any region or theme. I need all the block list

Comment: This is a simple function only. When you collect block information it has to be w.r.t to a theme only. It will give you a list of all active themes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how blocks are defined. There are numerous [hooks that are involved in providing a block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/7). Call the appropriate one using [module_invoke_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7) to gather the appropriate information about the blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your help i have got the list of block with following code:  $blocks = _block_rehash($theme);